# How to customize Xamarin.forms apps?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to change the default theme of xamarin (Theme.Material), I want to have a white background with gray/black writing.

How can I do it?

Is there a way to change the design for all the three plaforms at once without having to customize for different platforms?

Answer (score 0):

David Britch wrote a blogpost on Xamarin.forms Theming few days ago.

https://blog.xamarin.com/app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-control-templates

this gives a good start.

Answer (score 0):

*My answer describes how to do this for your Android app only - it does not address the other platforms. Since you mention "Material", which is an Android-only thing, it wasn't clear what your actual goals are. There is another answer presented that directs you to information on Forms-based theming, but that approach overrides Material.*

The easiest way to do this is by changing your Activity's Theme. Open MainActivity.cs and modify the attribute to specify it. For example, if you want to switch from the default dark theme to a light theme, you can change if from this:

```
[Activity (
    Label = "Demo.Droid",
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation
)]
```

to this:

```
[Activity (
    Label = "Demo.Droid",
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"
)]
```

If you want to customize the theme further, then you can add a `values` folder under your Android project's `Resources` folder, and add an xml file named `Styles.xml'. In this file, you can create custom theme based on the built-in theme. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/app_bar</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Those colors ("app_bar", "status_bar", "bg") need to be defined since I just made them up. To define colors, you add a `Colors.xml` file to the `values` folder, that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Purple hues -->
    <color name="app_bar" type="color">#FFE1BEE7</color>
    <color name="status_bar" type="color">#FFBA68C8</color>
    <color name="bg" type="color">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

And then you can reference that custom theme in your activity:

```
[Activity (
    Label = "Demo.Droid",
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    Theme = "@style/CustomTheme"
)]
```

This should give you a general idea of how to do it. The theme applied in this manner works for both a non-Forms app as well as a Forms app, assuming you aren't applying some manual font/color values through XAML or elsewhere in the app - in other words, the Android theme is used by default unless you override it.

You can find more information (including how to gracefully downgrade for non-Material devices) here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/